# iOS: Alert In Notification Center Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, datepicker

I wrote an app that will alert the user when a date is coming up. I have a date picker that I implemented and saved the entered date using this code in my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    NSDate *storedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];


    [self.datePicker setDate:storedDate animated:NO];
}
```

And this is the method that saves the data:

```
- (IBAction)dateChanged:(id)sender {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSDate *selectedDate = [self.datePicker date];


[defaults setObject:selectedDate forKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];}
```

I'm trying to have an alert in the notification center around 36 hours before the date using this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm'/'dd'/'yyyy"];
NSDate *eventDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:datePicker];

localNotif.fireDate = [eventDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-13*60*60];
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


localNotif.alertBody = @"Event tomorrow!";

localNotif.alertAction = nil;

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotif];    

return YES;
```

}

My issue is in the `dateFromString:datePicker`. I'm not sure what to put in there, I'm used to doing this with text fields, not pickers. Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You should split your notification-related question into a new one, generally there should be one question asked per post on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take the text from a hypothetical `UITextField`, set the `dateFromString:` parameter to something along these lines:

```
UITextField *textField;
[dateFormatter dateFromString:textField.text];
```

**EDIT**

If you want to take a date from a `UIDatePicker` as you describe in your comment, you can do something like this:

```
UIDatePicker *picker;
[dateFormatter stringFromDate:picker.date];
```

Comment: There actually is no text field in the nib, is it possible to grab the data straight from the date picker?